# How to Close a TCP/IP Connection

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I wasn't taught networking very well. I know the basics of TCP/IP, but I'm facing an assignment where I have to manage multiple threads for multiple projects that communicate with each other in the same solution. I'm working in Window's Forms, C#, and for simplicity's sake I'll write only what needs to be written.

This is my Client class, which connects to the Server, handles messages to and from the server, and logs out from the server.

```
private TcpClient ClientConnection = null;
private NetworkStream CommandStream = null;

private Thread ClientThread = null;
bool isRunning = false;

public Client()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
        //open the connection to the command port
        ClientConnection = new TcpClient(address, Convert.ToInt32(port));

        //Get the command stream
        CommandStream = ClientConnection.GetStream();
        if (CommandStream != null)
        {
            isConnected = true;
            ClientThread = new Thread(Receive);
            isRunning = true;
            ClientThread.Start();
        }
        errorLabel.Visible = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorLabel.Visible = true;
        errorLabel.Text = "Failed to Connect";
    }
}

private void Receive()
{
    Byte[] data = new Byte[1024];
    string message = string.Empty;
    int BytesReceived = 0;

    while (isRunning == true)
    {
        BytesReceived = CommandStream.Read(data, 0, 1024);
        message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, BytesReceived);

        //Do something with the message
    }
}

private void logoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do logout logic here
        errorLabel.Visible = false;

        try
        {
            if (ClientConnection != null)
            {
                Byte[] command = new Byte[1024];
                string commandStr = "SHUTDOWN";
                command = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(commandStr);
                CommandStream.Write(command, 0, command.GetLength(0));

                ClientConnection.Close();
                CommandStream.Close();
                isRunning = false;

                if (ClientThread.IsAlive == true)
                {
                    errorLabel.Visible = true;
                    errorLabel.Text = "Thread still alive. Failed to Disconnect";
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            errorLabel.Visible = true;
            errorLabel.Text = "Failed to Disconnect";
        }

    }
```

And this is my server class' Process Handler Function:

```
private void CommandProcessHandler(Socket client)
    {
        Byte[] data = new Byte[1024];
        NetworkStream NetStream = null;

        //Exception check
        if(client.Connected == true)
            NetStream = new NetworkStream(client);

        while(bCommandListener == true)
        {
            //Read the command from the client
            int bytes = NetStream.Read(data, 0, 1024);
            string Command = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

            //Do something with the command
            if (Command == "SHUTDOWN")
            {
                NetStream.Close();
                client.Close();
                bCommandListener = false;
                continue;
            }
            //Display the command in the command list box
            string buttonPressed;
            string buttonLetter;

            buttonPressed = CommandDataObject.Instance.DecodeUIDFromMessage(Command);
            buttonLetter = CommandDataObject.Instance.DecodeMessageFromUID(Command);

            Command = ((client.RemoteEndPoint) as IPEndPoint).Address.ToString() + ">>>" + Command;
            UpdateCommandsListBox(Command);
        } 
    }
```

I'm sure that I'm starting up the threads perfectly fine, but the issue lies in shutting them down. This was an aspect I was never properly taught, and am having trouble learning. As it stands, I press the "log out" button, which should send a message to the server to shutdown, as well as close the TcpClient and NetworkStream. It also sets the isRunning bool, which keeps the client's Receive thread active, to false.

However, as it stands, I keep getting an error when I do this, on line 98 (during the client's Receive function, when BytesReceived = CommandStream.Read) as follows:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.
```

I'm not sure what the error is referring to, but I've been stuck on this for a while and want to get it fixed. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use NetworkStream, it will throw an IOException if the underlying socket is closed while trying to read, [see MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . So your code is perfectly fine. You just have to handle the exception.

If you were to read the socket directly, you would just receive 0 when the socket is closed.

Comment: I suspected that was the case, but I still don't know how to avoid it. I set the bool to false, but it still executes the CommandStream.Read anyways, so the program always crashes due to an exception.

Comment: @Alfabit That is due to the fact that you are already reading the stream when you press the button on the other thread. Then when the other end disconnects, the Read call is just aborted. You can either change the reading to non-blocking, which would not throw exception, or just handle the exception with try...catch block.

Comment: This seems to have worked. The program no longer crashes upon logging out. Thank you Sami.